# Bitwise operations in Python coming from C

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I tried rewriting the small C program below in Python, but I am getting different outputs.

C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  unsigned char data = 0x00;
  unsigned char i;
  unsigned char bit = 0x01;
  unsigned char parity = 1;

  unsigned char value = 0x1c;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    data = data | bit;
    bit = bit << 1;
    parity = parity ^ (data & 0x01);
  }

  printf("data: %d bit: %d parity: %d\n", data, bit, parity);

  return 0;
}
```

Python version:

```
data = 0
bit = 1
parity = 1
value = int('1c', 16)

for i in range(8):
  data = data | bit
  bit = bit << 1
  parity = parity ^ (data & 1)

print('data: {0} bit: {1} parity: {2}'.format(data, bit, parity))
```

And the outputs are:

C version

```
> $ ./test
data: 255 bit: 0 parity: 1
```

Python version

```
> $ python3 test.py
data: 255 bit: 256 parity: 1
```

What am I missing on Python bitwise operations?

Comment: You're missing _'ctypes'_

Comment: You are missing that your type is larger than a byte. As such: 128 << 1 = 256 and does not overflow to 0

Comment: @planetmaker, yep; _ctypes_ module is somewhat awkward but consistent way to deal with it. Although not "pythonic" at all )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see, the only difference in the output is the value of the variable `bit`.

In your C program, the variable `bit` is declared as `unsigned char`. That means it takes on only the values `0` through `255`. The last operation on `bit` in your code is

```
bit = bit << 1
```

Before the last time that line is executed, `bit` is `128`. After that line, it "tries" to become `256` but that does not fit into an `unsigned char`. So overflow happens, not flagged by your program, and `bit` becomes `0`.

In the Python program, the variable `bit` is simply an integer, `int`, which has no maximum size. So there is no overflow, and `bit` does become `256`.

There are several ways to overcome that difference in Python.  You could force `bit` to stay in the desired range by instead using

```
bit = (bit << 1) % 256
```

or perhaps

```
bit = (bit << 1) & 255
```

You could instead make `bit` to be the equivalent of an `unsigned char` variable. As a comment says, you could use the `ctypes` module, I believe. You could also use `numpy` (I'm more familiar with that).

Comment: Exactly, Python is not aware about "small" integer types…

Comment: @RoryDaulton Maybe you should rephrase it, considering google will match this some day: "In the Python program, bit is just an integer."

Comment: @agg3l: I rephrased it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Confusing naming of variables in Python code sample (assuming byte-aware integer types, which are not really there) by kolrie has already and may lead to more confusion later. As long as Python is not low-level language by design. That was my idea

Comment: @RoryDaulton Just think of (yours) quote "bit [value] is 128"… What ???.
It does not applies to yours answer which is absolutely correct; the form only.
Forget it, sorry